# Best way to start working-out again after a break

Tags: training

If i just started to work out after a 4-5 week break would it be best to start slowly or just pick up my old pace? The 'sport' im referring to is fitness. Im currently debating with myself whether or not i should imediatly go back to 4-5 days a week training or if i should start with training day followed by resting day followed by training day etc. The most i do is cardio followed by abdominal excercises. I usually dedicate 1-2 days (depending on the amount of days i excercise that week) to weights followed by a resting day. After a weekend of partying (eating unhealthy/drinking alcohol/little excercise) i would proceed that week with a lot of cardio and a minimum amount of weights (usually around 3-4-5 days cardio and 0-1 days weight (or a bit of weights after cardio)). Although this might not be the best for my muscles it did feel like the best thing to do.

So to my question: Yesterday was the first day of excercise in about 4-5 weeks (holiday and work, etc). Would it be wise to just start head-on and go for my 'old' scedule or just start slowly for a week or two and just do 3 days a week at first.

I know this could be considered opinion based but lets add some facts about muscles or something to make it specific.

Thanks a lot in advance anyway.